Stored procedures in Snowflake Scripting in SQL Language where the goal is to drop some tables
I'm trying to create a stored procedure in Snowflake where I need to perform a statement to drop some tables in my warehouse. But I'm getting this error:

The SQL query doesn't contain any SELECT statement

USE SCHEMA "PUBLIC";

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DROP_TABLE()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
exec_sql VARCHAR;
BEGIN

    SELECT LISTAGG('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "' || SF_DATABASE || '"."' || SF_SCHEMA || '"."' || SF_TABLE || '";') 
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SF_DATABASE, SF_SCHEMA, SF_TABLE) 
    INTO exec_sql
    FROM WAREHOUSE.PUBLIC.DATASETS;
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE exec_sql;
    
    RETURN exec_sql;

END;
$$;

CALL DROP_TABLE();


Does the error happen when this stored procedure is created, or when it is called?

the error happens when i call the procedure

Then we need to see exactly how it is called.

this is how i call: CALL DROP_TABLE();

That's not what I meant.  How are you executing this sql script?  Are you running it from a SQL database client?  Are you running it inside some python or java code?

I'm running in Dataiku as environment for executing SQL scripts. the error i provide its from Dataiku, when i run it in Snowflake the output is null value

Should the INTO exec_sql be INTO :exec_sql ??

Snowflake Scripting - EXECUTE IMMEDIATE multiple statements to drop tables without loop/cursor
